# how to make web browser in Xcode load a web page automatically

Tags: xcode, browser

I am building a web browser in Xcode cocoa application, using the interface builder. I have it all working when it comes to typing in web address and clicking go.

but I would like for it to automatically load a web page instead of seeing white when I open my project, I looked in inspector to see if you can set a specific web address but I couldn't find anything to do this.

Comment: Try watching this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XWhcnIxrtMk

Answer (score 0):

How about if you load the URL that you would like in the viewdidload function:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:WebsitePath];
         NSURLRequest *WebRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];
        [self.WebViewer loadRequest:WebRequest];
        self.WebViewer.scalesPageToFit = YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to load the WebView when the application finish launching,just add the URL Request in the applicationDidFinishLauching parameter,else if your WebView is on the MainView you can add a loadingScreen that appear while the webView is loading!
Lucky!